# C# Sendkeys with formatted text

Tags: c#, html, rtf, sendkeys

So, I'm trying to send formatted text(RTF or HTML format) using SendKeys.Send, is this possible?

The only way that I found in order to do this: Set the text to clipboard and then paste it, but after doing some research I've found that this isn't a good practice and also I can't find a way to restore the clipboard after I paste the formatted text.

Comment: It's typically bad practice to send keys at all.  You should at least be confirming the correct application has focus but even then you could be focused on a different element in the application vs where you really want it inputting text.  What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: The application is already focused, what I am trying to do: when a user types a shortcut it will be replaced with something else and also can be replaced with an image+text(so formatted text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've solved this, when I was restoring the clipboard I didn't had any delays and because of that it wasn't working properly, now after I've added a small delay everything is working fine, in case someone have the same problem.